# Add TCL binding to a fairly large C++ code base

Tags: tcl, swig

I have a C++ project whose source files are distributed over several trees. Currently each is built into a static library and finally the main() function is compiled and linked with all those libraries through static link.

Now I am using SWIG to add TCL binding to the project. The examples I can find all are simple, just one C++ source.

My understanding is, I need to re-compile each library to be shared libraries, compile the SWIFT binding code to a shared library and link all these libraries into one. In TCL, I load that final one.

For example, here is my source tree:

```
dir1: s1.c
dir2: s2.c
dir3: swig_binding.c
```

My action plan to the above source tree is:

1. Update the Makefiles so that I have

   ```
   dir1: libs1.so
   dir2: libs2.so
   dir3: libswig_binding.so
   ```
2. Link the 3 .so files into one, `libswig_binding.so`
3. Inside TCL, `load libswig_binding.so`

Do you see if I miss anything?